# Google Docs API. Java Specific Resumable Upload

Tags: java, gdata-api

I have been working with the google docs api found here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#introduction

This issue I'm having is that when you get past the authentication sections there is no more java specific information. I been able to write most of my program by going through example code i found here: 
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/docs

I need to write a method to update a plain text file using "resumable upload" but I cannot find any information on how to do this in Java. I attempted to translate the .NET script found on the first link with no luck.  Been working on this for two days now and I'm officially stuck.

If anyone knows how to do this or knows of any other java specific resources for this API that would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some good java sample code here. 
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/docs/DocumentResumableUploadDemo.java